# Converting date to day of week

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

is there any ready to go solution within the microsoft framework, regarding conversion of date to day?

For example, i would like to convert this string **21/03/2010** (dd/mm/yyyy) to **Sunday**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim d = DateTime.Parse("21/03/2010").DayOfWeek()
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will print Sunday on the console window

```
    Dim dateToShow as DateTime =  new DateTime(2010, 03,21)

    Console.WriteLine(dateToShow.DayOfWeek.ToString)
```

Comment: I recommend you include a DateTime.Parse() statement in your code sample to explain how to parse his original input of "21/03/2010" rather than just hard-coding it.

Answer (score 1):

This should print "Sunday".

```
   string myDateTimeString = "21/03/2010";

   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
        myDateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
        new CultureInfo("en-Us", true)
        , DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

   Console.WriteLine(dt.DayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use DateTime.TryParse() just to validate the user input.

```
Dim input As String = "2010/12/23"
Dim dateTime As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParse(input, dateTime) Then
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.DayOfWeek)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid")
End If
```